# autostart on jquery kwicks

Tags: jquery-plugins

is it possible to add an autostart option to jquery kwicks?

i just want it to do the same animation automatically even if the user is not overing it:
the user load the page and if he's not interacting with the element the animation starts automatically, then if he interacts with it it works normally with the mouseover event. in the setup i can declare a different event than the mouseover, but what i need is to add the automatic start to the function

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. On default, the kwicks elements respond to the mouseover event. The easiest way to build an animation is to trigger the mouseover event on the elements. For example: `$("#kwick_1").mouseover()`

Of course, mouse events will still disturb the animation. If you do not want this, use your own event. At kwicks setup, pass `event: 'myevent'` in the options object and in the animation, call `$("#kwicks_1").trigger('myevent');`. If you don't want the mouse events, you probably also want to pass `sticky: true`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i would try to keep both, i mean:
the user load the page and if he's not interacting with the element the animation starts automatically, then if he interacts with it it works normally with the mouseover event.
in the setup i can declare a different event than the mouseover, but what i need is to add the automatic start to the function